# haskell quick sort complexity?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, haskell, time-complexity

I run the below quick sort Haskell function (using merge and sort algorithm):

```
qsort []=[]
qsort (x:xs) =
  qsort smaller ++ [x] ++ qsort larger
    where
      smaller = [a | a <- xs , a<x ] -- edit
      larger  = [b | b <- xs , b>=x ]
```

In order to test the runtime for this for a bit big amount of data, I run the below code:

```
qsort [100000,99999..0]
```

It takes till now 40 min and it is still running! Even a list of 100,000 is not that big, so:

1. how could I handle data a billion of data?
2. is this sort algorithm(merge and sort) takes less time in other language like C#, python...is this  a problem in haskell language
3. how could I predict the runtime of an algorithm using its complexity?

Comment: The first element is an awful choice of pivot. Also, your duplicate handling is outright wrong; any duplicates of the pivot go into both `smaller` and `larger`!

Comment: Quick sort is in-place! This is not quick sort.

Comment: You also need to ensure that *all* occurrences of `x` appear in the output if it is not a unique value.

Comment: @dotctor I can't find anything that says quicksort must be in-place (in fact, I can only find things that suggest that it is *usually*, but not always, in-place). The pivot choice isn't very effective here, but I would still say it's quicksort.

Comment: it should not get in infinite recursion , i have tried it on the list [10..1] and it works even the first element is the bigger one

Comment: @chepner This shouldn't cause an infinite loop because, at most, `smaller` and `larger` can only contain the tail of the list given to `qsort`.

Comment: Worry about correctness before efficiency. Try running a test on a small data set first.

Comment: @chris ,It is correct, i have  tried it on [1000..1] and it works fine in a short amount of time.

Comment: Sorry, didn't look closely enough to see that `a` is pulled from `xs`, not `(x:xs)`.

Comment: @DavidYoung, I would say that QuickSort does not have to be in place, but that it absolutely requires a way to choose a pivot such that for some `p > 0` and `r < 1/2`, the probability that the pivot is no more than `ceil (r * n)` places from the median is at least `p`. This generally means randomized pivoting, but you could make a case for median-of-medians or similar.

Comment: @chepner, so the smallest will return the whole list and the largest will return and empty list, nothing to do with empty list and the function will continue recursivley with quick sort smaller

Comment: @khaledomar If the pivot is ever a non-unique value, it will be duplicated in the two results: `sort [1,2,3,2] => [1,2,2,2,3]`.

Comment: @khaledomar `qsort [(),()]` evaluates to `[(),(),()]`. I'd recommend property testing with [quickcheck](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/QuickCheck).

Comment: @dotctor Since you are nitpicking: Quicksort is **usually not** strictly speaking in-place. It uses O(log n) space (for the recursive calls stack). In-place means O(1) memory usage (which means the only recursive calls you can do must be tail-recursive). Heapsort is usually implemented in-place.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The worst case time of quicksort is *n<sup>2</sup>*. Your implementation uses the first element as the pivot, which results in worst-case performance when the input is sorted (or sorted in reverse).

To get quicksort to perform at its expected complexity of *n* log *n*, you need either randomized pivot selection, or to randomly shuffle the input before sorting.

Comment: To sort use sort shuffle then sort the sort shuffled sorts?